# Can someone explain the following snippet of R code?

Tags: r, machine-learning

Specifically, what the 3rd line of code does and how does 'train[train$label==1,]' work

```
   train <- read.csv("../input/train.csv")
   set.seed(71)
   data <- sample(as.integer(row.names(train[train$label==1,])),100)
   par(mfrow=c(10,10),mar=c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1))  ---- 3
```

Comment: You're better off looking for some basic/introductory R tutorials. There are ample such resources (including many free) on the tag page, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It subsets the train dataset to only observations where label = 1.

Comment: Sorry, if this is a silly question. But is 'label' a column name of the data or an inbuilt property of data frame?

Comment: Column name, please follow advice in the first comment.

Comment: Yeah I would do some intro tutorials. SO isn’t really the place for trying to understand what a piece of code means. If tutorial and google before posting. SO is more for posting a reproducible example of an issue you’re having with a script.